# JS break when running RevealJS on an Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js

I have a bug with use of RevealJS on an Ipad.
My web-app is break and stop the JS run on this line:

```
Vb.slides.classList.remove("no-transition")
```

The debugger says:"Result of expression Vb.slides.classList[undefined] is not an object

I don't know the way or a cheating to resolve that.
I use the last version of Reveal.min.js : https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/js/reveal.min.js

Is anyone have already the same issue?

Comment: Resolved with addition of the classList plugin to Reveal